# iOS Swift - Cannot Change Animation Options with Array [UIViewAnimationOptions]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, animation, swift2

I have some problem about animation options with `array` in Swift 2. I can add multiple options in `array` like this : `[.Repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse]` and this is if I add in animation function (first example) :

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse], animations: {

    }) { (true) in

    }
```

But I cannot add animation options in `array` like this (second example) :

```
var animationOptions = [UIViewAnimationOptions]()
animationOptions.append(UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat)
animationOptions.append(UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse)
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: animationOptions, animations: {

    }) { (true) in

    }
```

Can someone help me make animation options in array like second example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    var animationOptions:UIViewAnimationOptions = .repeat
    animationOptions.insert(.autoreverse)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.1, options: animationOptions, animations: {

    }) { (success:Bool) in

    }
```

You need to use the insert from the SetAlgebra Protocol, which the OptionSet conforms to. In the question you are using the Array Object instead of the UIViewAnimationOptions.

Comment: Waooow, Thanks a lot @New16. This answer my questions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation option like this:

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.Repeat, 
.Autoreverse, .CurveLinear, .CurveEaseOut, .CurveEaseInOut,
.TransitionCurlUp, .TransitionCurlDown, 
.TransitionFlipFromBottom,.TransitionFlipFromLeft,.TransitionFlipFromRight, 
.BeginFromCurrentState, .CurveEaseIn], animations: {}, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, 
.autoreverse, .curveLinear, .curveEaseOut, .curveEaseInOut,
.transitionCurlUp, .transitionCurlDown, 
.transitionFlipFromBottom,.transitionFlipFromLeft,.transitionFlipFromRight, 
.beginFromCurrentState, .curveEaseIn], animations: {}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I need multiple animation options in array so I can add infinite animation option.
please view second example in my question.

Comment: UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .CurveLinear, .CurveEaseOut, .CurveEaseInOut, .TransitionCurlUp, .TransitionCurlDown, .TransitionFlipFromBottom,.TransitionFlipFromLeft,.TransitionFlipFromRight, .BeginFromCurrentState, .CurveEaseIn], animations: {}, completion: nil)

Comment: can you add this values in array variable ?  "[.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .CurveLinear, .CurveEaseOut, .CurveEaseInOut, .TransitionCurlUp, .TransitionCurlDown, .TransitionFlipFromBottom,.TransitionFlipFromLeft,.Transitio‌​nFlipFromRight, .BeginFromCurrentState, .CurveEaseIn]"